# page life cycle and textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, pageload

enter code hereI make dynamic textboxes when dropdownlist change item with autopostback. Later i want to get the text of textboxes when a submit button activated. But when button activated the textboxes return blank character. The problem must be due to page life . What techniques should I use to get these values?

```
    public class GuiOtherAuthors
    {
        public OtherAuthors[] tableOtherAuthors;
        public Label[] lblName;
        public TextBox[] txtName;
        public Label[] lblSurname;
        public TextBox[] txtSurname;
        public Label[] lblInstitution;
        public TextBox[] txtInstitution;
        public Label[] lblCountry;
        public TextBox[] txtCountry;
        public Label[] lblEmail;
        public TextBox[] txtEmail;
        public PlaceHolder PlaceHolder1 = new PlaceHolder();

        public Int32 NumberOfAutherOthos { set; get; }


        public void InitializeControls()
        {
            tableOtherAuthors = new OtherAuthors[NumberOfAutherOthos];
            lblName = new Label[NumberOfAutherOthos];
            txtName = new TextBox[NumberOfAutherOthos];
            lblSurname = new Label[NumberOfAutherOthos];
            txtSurname = new TextBox[NumberOfAutherOthos];
            lblInstitution = new Label[NumberOfAutherOthos];
            txtInstitution = new TextBox[NumberOfAutherOthos];
            lblCountry = new Label[NumberOfAutherOthos];
            txtCountry = new TextBox[NumberOfAutherOthos];
            lblEmail = new Label[NumberOfAutherOthos];
            txtEmail = new TextBox[NumberOfAutherOthos];

            for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfAutherOthos; i++)
            {
                lblName[i] = new Label();
                lblName[i].Text = "Name:";
                txtName[i] = new TextBox();
                lblSurname[i] = new Label();
                lblSurname[i].Text = "Surname:";
                txtSurname[i] = new TextBox();
                lblInstitution[i] = new Label();
                lblInstitution[i].Text = "Institution:";
                txtInstitution[i] = new TextBox();
                lblCountry[i] = new Label();
                lblCountry[i].Text = "Country:";
                txtCountry[i] = new TextBox();
                lblEmail[i] = new Label();
                lblEmail[i].Text = "Email:";
                txtEmail[i] = new TextBox();
            }

        }
        public PlaceHolder makeGUI()
        {
            int i = 0;
            int j = 1;



            for (i = 0; i < NumberOfAutherOthos; i++)
            {
                Label authorInformation = new Label();
                authorInformation.Text = "Information for Author " + j.ToString() + " :";
                lblName[i].Text = "Name:";
                lblSurname[i].Text = "Surname:";
                lblInstitution[i].Text = "Institution:";
                lblCountry[i].Text = "Country:";
                lblEmail[i].Text = "Email:";

                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<table>"));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span style=\"font-weight:bold;\" "));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(authorInformation);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</span>"));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td>"));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblName[i]);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td>"));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txtName[i]);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr>"));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td>"));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblSurname[i]);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td>"));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txtSurname[i]);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr>"));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td>"));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblInstitution[i]);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td>"));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txtInstitution[i]);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr>"));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td>"));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblCountry[i]);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td>"));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txtCountry[i]);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr>"));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td>"));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblEmail[i]);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td>"));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txtEmail[i]);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr>"));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</table><br /> "));
                j++;
            }
            return PlaceHolder1;

        }
    }

The code is in c#
Thanks

 this is my page load:


    private GuiOtherAuthors gui = new GuiOtherAuthors();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            numberOfOtherAuthors = NumberOfOtherAuthors();
            if (!numberOfOtherAuthors.Equals(0))
            {
                gui.NumberOfAutherOthos = numberOfOtherAuthors;
                gui.InitializeControls(); //Initialize the textboes
                Panel1.Controls.Add(gui.makeGUI()); .. create my gui 
                setValueofOtherAuthors(numberOfOtherAuthors); //create object with value of textboxes
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: the code are many lines but below is the pageLoad function
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            numberOfOtherAuthors = NumberOfOtherAuthors();
            if (!numberOfOtherAuthors.Equals(0))
            {
                gui.NumberOfAutherOthos = numberOfOtherAuthors;
                gui.InitializeControls();
                Panel1.Controls.Add(gui.makeGUI());
                setValueofOtherAuthors(numberOfOtherAuthors);
            }
        }

A small example i  need to understand the techniques should i do

Comment: Edit and place your code in the question body :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the controls early in the life-cycle's Page_Init() handler and grab the text box values late in the life-cycle's OnPreRender handler.

Comment: can you tell me an example based on the scenario described

Comment: Just move your existing logic for creating the DDLs and reading the text box values to the appropriate handler methods...

Comment: Save the DDL values ion ViewState. Override the LoadViewState and SaveViewState methods to set and get the values. This should work for you. Search these terms on SO and you will find other similar examples :)

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head, so I may have the event wrong, but in Page_Init(?) you need to add any dynamically added controls in order to get their value during the rest of the postback cycle.

Comment: can you tell me an example based on the scenario described

Comment: When I've done this, I've kept track of what components I added by using Session State.  Then on future postbacke I look in session state to see what I need, and add the controls the same way I did in the dynamic event.  I'd have to see the code where you are adding the textboxes to give a more specific example.